# Is there a way to programmatically create a custom Power Plan in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

So I had an idea, but maybe this is impossible to do. Is there a way within the .NET framework to programmatically create and assign a custom power plan on a Windows machine (preferably in C#).

At work we always have to set the power plan settings by hand for a new machine. It would be nice if this was automated when the machine was being set up. As you might imagine, doing this for hundreds of machines is a bit tedious.

So is this possible? If this is impossible, then is there a clever way around this?

I'm thinking that WMI might be a good place to look for this functionality.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Allan Elder's answer below may be what you need in terms of programatically doing this through code.  **BUT** I can't help but to wonder, it seems that you are responsible for the machines, and as such I'd assume the infrastructure, if true, then why don't you do this through a GPO in Active Directory where all this is intended to be managed from?

Comment: @Jason: These machines are not part of our domain. They are given to people who work offsite. So that's not really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Windows API Code Pack, which is a wrapper around many of the Windows API

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

You'll be able to access the Power Management APIs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373163%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: So what I ended up doing is much like you suggested. I ended up just using PInvoke to gain access to the methods housed in Power Management and made a PowerManager class around the methods that I Imported. Definitely was a lot of fun. :-)